# jQuery plugin change values of static variables

Tags: jquery, variables, plugins, static

I have following code:

```
(function($){
    $.fn.aRSSFeed = function(options) {

        //  defaultne nastavenia triednych premennych

        $.aRSSFeed = {
            minHeight:          0,
            widgetPerPage:      9,
            initializedWidgets: 0,
            borderAround:       'centralBorder',
            widgetPerRow:       3,
            maxSavedFeeds:      24
        };

})(jQuery);
```

And I want to change value of static variable `widgetPerPage` from outside, before initializations of individuals objects for elements with the plugin.

How I do it? I tried following:

```
    $.fn.aRSSFeed({
        maxSavedFeeds: 50
    });
```

or:

```
$.fn.aRSSFeed.maxSavedFeeds = 50;
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you forgot a closing brace: the one you opened with `$.fn.aRSSFeed = function(options) {`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you missed closing brace `}` of `$.fn.aRSSFeed = function(options) {`

```
(function($){
    $.fn.aRSSFeed = function(options) {

        //  defaultne nastavenia triednych premennych

        $.aRSSFeed = {
            minHeight:          0,
            widgetPerPage:      9,
            initializedWidgets: 0,
            borderAround:       'centralBorder',
            widgetPerRow:       3,
            maxSavedFeeds:      24
        };
    }  // you missed this brace

})(jQuery);

   $.fn.aRSSFeed.maxSavedFeeds = 50;
   console.log($.fn.aRSSFeed.maxSavedFeeds);
```

Comment: but then there is no default setting. `console.log($.fn.aRSSFeed.maxSavedFeeds);` before setting the value will be `undefined`

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
$.aRSSFeed.maxSavedFeeds = 50
```

EDIT: and yes, you missed a closing } bracket like the others said

Answer (score 0):

```
(function($){
    $.fn.aRSSFeed = function(options) {

        //  defaultne nastavenia triednych premennych

        $.aRSSFeed = $.extend({
            minHeight:          0,
            widgetPerPage:      9,
            initializedWidgets: 0,
            borderAround:       'centralBorder',
            widgetPerRow:       3,
            maxSavedFeeds:      24
        }, options);
    };

})(jQuery);
```